# How to add person to a photo in Photos app

Tags: iphone, photos.app

I'd like to (manually?) add people "tags" to photos in the Photos app that were not recognized automatically. How would I do this?

My phone recognizes pictures of my baby from the front just fine but I'd like for photos taken of her back-side, for example, get tagged to her as well.

I have an iPhone 11 and a Windows laptop.

Answer (score 1):

This is only possible using the Photos app on Mac. The iPhone photos app does not contain the functionality to add missing faces.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible yet. You can only add people when their faces appear on the photo.

If it hasn't detected all the faces in your pictures yet you have to leave your phone charging and locked.